# How to replace specifically the nth word in a string in SAS

Tags: string, replace, sas

In sas, how can I replace specifically the i-th word in a string?

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
myString = 'aa cccc ddd aa aa 0.85645';
```

(=6 words) where I don't know the length of each word, I only know they are separated by spaces.

how can I replace the i-th string with something else like

*e.g.* if i=4
and I want replace the word with 'bbbbb':

```
myNewString = 'aa cccc ddd bbbbb aa 0.85645';
```

I'm looking for a function that would be some sort of a combination of `scan(myString,4,' ')` and `tranwrd`.

The problem here is that I can't combine them because the 1st word might be the same and the 4th word and thus I can't target specifically a tranwrd on the 4th word. I also can't use find() for the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call SCAN make this easy.

```
38         data _null_;
39            String = 'aa cccc ddd aa aa 0.85645';
40            call scan(string,4,p,l,' ');
41            string2 = substrn(string,1,p-1)||'Dummy'||substrn(string,p+l);
42            put _all_;
43            run;

String=aa cccc ddd aa aa 0.85645 p=13 l=2 string2=aa cccc ddd Dummy aa 0.85645 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Comment: Cool. Note using l for length makes the code a little hard to read since `p+l` looks a lot like `p+1`. :)

Comment: Yes, but if I understand the question, you can not know the length of the string before. So, we don't know the value of p and l, because it can change. So, I prefer the answer of user667489.

Comment: @D.O. The values of P and L are what CALL SCAN returns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this. Regex might also be worth looking into.

```
data example;
myString = 'aa cccc ddd aa aa 0.85645';
length myWord  $32 t_myString $1000;
myWord = 'Dummy';
do i = 1 by 1 while (myWord ne '');
myWord = scan(myString,i,' ');
if i = 4 then myWord = 'bbbbb';
t_mystring = catx(' ',t_myString,myWord);
end;
myString = t_myString;
drop myWord t_myString;
run;
```

Comment: I think this is the good answer, because myString can be any string.